# SQLite - Prevent a slow CTE being evaulated multiple times

Tags: sqlite

I'm using a CTE to do a slow-ish query on a large table. The CTE produces a small number of results that I'm using several times in a UNION clause, like this:

```
WITH slow_cte(x,y,z) AS (SELECT ... FROM large_table WHERE ...)
SELECT x FROM slow_cte UNION SELECT y FROM slow_cte UNION SELECT z FROM slow_cte
```

The slow query on its own takes X seconds to complete. But this query takes 3X seconds to complete, suggesting that the CTE is being executed 3 times. The SQLite documentation states that a [CTE works in the same way as a temporary view](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html). I've also tested querying a slow view in the same way, and it has the same performance problem.

**Is there any way to get SQLite to cache the results of a CTE to improve peformance? I would like to avoid creating a temporary table if possible.**

Here is a standalone query that demonstrates my problem:

```
WITH 
  RECURSIVE large_table(x, y, z) AS 
    (VALUES(0,0,0) UNION ALL SELECT x+1, 'Y' || (x+1), 'Z' || (x+1)  FROM large_table WHERE x<500000),
  slow_cte(x, y, z) AS 
    (SELECT x, y, z FROM large_table WHERE x%100000 = 1)
SELECT x FROM slow_cte UNION SELECT y from slow_cte UNION SELECT z FROM slow_cte
```

On my machine, this query takes ~4 seconds to run, but around ~1s if I change the last line to `SELECT x FROM slow_cte`

Comment: Is `slow_cte` a recursive one? If so, read the optimization notes in the section on recursive CTEs [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html).

Comment: No, just a normal CTE. The recursive one above is just for the standalone example.

Comment: You'd have to create a temporary table explicitly.